# Change Spreadsheet Settings from gspread

Tags: python, gspread

Is there any way to change **Spreadsheet Settings** from the api??

Is there any other way I can do this from python??

Im using gspread to pull the results of a google form into python. 
I want to change the **time zone** of the results to fit to my needs, since my local time and form's time don't match.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to change those settings.
However, you can use python's datetime module to convert the time to time zone you want.